# Prevent iTunes from opening when connecting bluetooth headset

Tags: itunes, mac, bluetooth

Every time I connect my bluetooth headset to my Mac, iTunes decides it's time to launch.  Is there a way I can prevent this behavior?

I found this thread, but there is no solution: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2570254?start=0&tstart=0

- OS X 10.8.3
- iTunes 11.0.2 (26)
- Using Beats Wireless

---

#### Update

Even after removing iTunes from my computer, it stills prompts me to "find iTunes" whenever a bluetooth audio device is connected.

Comment: check iTunes preference settings!

Comment: If you list your headset's Bluetooth profile or just the exact model, there might be an answer by disabling the play/pause functionality that could be built into the device.

Comment: Please be more specific, and provide more detailed information. Computer type, operatings system, iTune version,...

Comment: Updated with my info

Comment: The workaround to disable Itunes helper does not work. Ituneshelper will re appear after login even if removed. I have actually gone and found the ituneshelper.app file and renamed it and itunes continues to start when my headset is turned on! As to the workaround with terminal and renaming files that completely disabled my keyboard on my macbook air! Be very careful using this! Luckily i was able to reset the computer using a bluetooth keyboard to recover. There is really no help in this thread for OSX 10.9 using itunes.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Extending Steve's answer, plus some tips from this [apple discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2570254?start=15&tstart=0), here's what I did that finally solved this.

1. Create a "Do Nothing App": open Automator, create an empty application, and save it as `DoNothingApp.app`
2. Rename iTunes (manually in the Applications directory, or using this terminal command):

   ```
   sudo mv /Applications/iTunes.app /Applications/iTunesBACK.app
   ```
3. Make a copy of DoNothingApp.app as iTunes.app (manually, or using this terminal command):

   ```
   sudo cp -R /Applications/DoNothingApp.app /Applications/iTunes.app
   ```

That's it. Of course, the real iTunes is now called iTunesBACK.

Comment: I found an an app that disables the play/pause media key. This might work for the bluetooth issue as well, and if so, it's a better solution than the one I propose above. http://redth.info/itunes-media-hotkey-disabler/

Comment: Won't this break updates that include iTunes?

Comment: @Paul, I'd bet 99% that it will break the update or something. I really don't care, iTunes is breaking my workflow with this stupid behavior. Bounty on its way, Joe, thanks!

Comment: This no longer works for me on 10.11, but @mritun's solution below does.

Comment: Funnily enough, this works in High Sierra, but the one below dowsn't due to System Integrity Protection.

Comment: It's unbelievable that a hack like this is required for something so simple. Little things like this are what's made me decide to switch back to PC and Android when it's time to get new devices.

Comment: In order to get this to work with High Sierra you must first disable system integrity protection. You can do that by restarting in recovery mode (hold down cmd-R when you restart your computer), launching terminal from Utilities menu, then executing `csrutil disable` and restarting.

Comment: This solution is no longer necessary in the latest versions of iTunes, see https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/299336/299627

Comment: That would no longer help on MacOS versions after 10.13, that have SIP (system integrity protection) enabled where you can't move/rename/modify key system components - to which, alas, iTunes is bound.

Answer (score 95):

I've got this figured out.

On OSX, the "RCD" (remote control daemon) is responsible for the naughtiness. It has hard-coded list of actions to do when it detects certain "events" - one of them being connecting to a bluetooth headset.

To disable this behaviour (minimal loss of functionality, possibly your apple remote won't work), use the following two commands:

```
launchctl stop com.apple.rcd 
launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.rcd.plist
```

This should stop rcd from being launched by OSX. No rcd - no auto-magic multimedia. Your volume keys should continue working, but things like play key (or bluetooth) auto-starting iTunes should stop. With `-w` option the change should be persistent.

PS: The following is the nuclear option. In Terminal, enter:

```
sudo chmod 000 /System/Library/CoreServices/rcd.app/Contents/MacOS/rcd
sudo pkill -9 rcd
```

To stop rcd from even being started by any app. To restore your rcd, use:

```
sudo chmod 755 /System/Library/CoreServices/rcd.app/Contents/MacOS/rcd
launchctl start com.apple.rcd
```

Comment: Finally!  Something that works on Yosemite

Comment: None of these options worked for me on 10.9.5 using Beats Wireless.

Comment: Worked on 10.10.3 using Apple EarPods.

Comment: On a MacBook Air with OS X 10.9.5, this worked (while the accepted answer of renaming the ITunes app did not, as the system would just launch the renamed app). THANK YOU.

Comment: Didn't work for me on OS X 10.9.5 with a Bose headset.

Comment: That worked for me on Yosemite

Comment: What are the side effects of this workaround? Does it just prevent iTunes from opening when a bluetooth headset is affected? Also when you mean the play key, is that the play key on the keyboard or the bluetooth device?

Comment: This is sooo weird, but using this fix causes my logitech wireless mouse to stop working. The clicking still works, but the mouse no longer moves. When I reload (e.g. `launchctl load -w ...`, `launchctl start ...`, unplug the logitech dongle, plug it back in), my mouse starts working again. I tried it 3 times and every time my mouse stops working.

Comment: This worked great however now in OSX 10.12.1 when you type: sudo chmod 000 I get 'Operation not permitted.' Anyone know a way around that?

Comment: @DavidNelson type "sudo su -" first and enter your password. This will elevate your permissions.

Comment: It's important once you unload it to do the `sudo chmod 000 /System/Library/CoreServices/rcd.app/Contents/MacOS/rcd`  All kinds of crap manually will start RCD (sometimes the play button, sometimes headphone built in controls).  This seem also something you might need to do periodically--apple likes to undo you local changes like this during updates/os upgrades

Comment: macOS High Sierra 10.13.2 `\/System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.rcd.plist: Operation not permitted while System Integrity Protection is engaged`

Comment: As A B says above, this is no longer a functional solution for High Sierra.

Comment: After I did this with Mavericks my iTunes still popped up. More importantly, now a movement of my Logitech bluetooth (with USB dongle) mouse is waking up the Mac. This was not the case before. I had to press the USB keyboard to wake it up. Any ideas on how to fix this? I already restored the rcd and rebooted.

Comment: Works like a champ on Catalina!  FINALLY!!

Comment: To unload is sadly no longer working for 12.2.1. Anyone has the same issue or a solution?
```❯ launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.rcd.plist
Unload failed: 5: Input/output error
Try running `launchctl bootout` as root for richer errors.```

Answer (score 38):

I'm on Catalina and it is now 2019. I was having Apple Music open every time I connected my bluetooth earbuds (Echo Buds). Since I never use Apple Music this worked for me:

- In Apple Music go to "Preferences..." and "Restrictions"
- Click all the checkboxes under "Disable" including one for "Apple Music"
- Click the lock to prevent further changes
- Click "OK"

As far as I know, this will prevent you from using Apple Music completely, which may not be an acceptable solution for everyone.

Comment: This worked for me in Catalina.

Comment: This worked for me High Sierra 10.13.4 -- I know, I know.  I should upgrade.

Comment: Doesn't work in Catalina for me. Using Jabra Elite 75 Headphones.

Comment: Worked for sony wf-1000xm3 on Catalina

Comment: thx for posting. Works for me. Mojave. I don't listen to iTunes  on my work laptop but it always popups when I turn on headphones for meetings. Was annoying me for months. iTunes should have this option build in derp.

Comment: Thanks! That is such a weird behaviour, normally I have my headphones connected to two devices at once my phone and then the laptop. Every time I end a call the headset automatically connects to the Mac and an obnoxiously loud song starts playing... Hope this fix works.

Comment: Didn't work for me with on Catalina 10.15.5 with Sony headphones

Comment: Worked for me on Catalina 10.15.7 and Sony WH-1000XM4

Comment: Interestingly it did **not** work for me on on Catalina 10.15.7 with Sony WH-1000XM4. So I expect there is some other difference here is causing the solution to not work for some (including me).

Comment: On Big-Sur this only half works. When my B&W PX headphones are connected - they won't auto-play or launch iTunes. However, if I then take them off my head, and put them on again - sure enough, it'll launch iTunes and start to play the first song in my library. I can't express my frustration from this. I could bear an 'auto-resume' of what was played - but hard-start-play-just-anything is so annoying.

Comment: Didn't work for me.

Answer (score 14):

[Solution](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2570254?start=15&tstart=0) explained by [imp68](https://discussions.apple.com/people/Imp68) worked for me

Short version:

- Remove iTunesHelper from your user's Login items

Step by step version:

- Open "**System Preferences**"
- Click "**Users & Groups**"
- Select your user
- Click "**Login Items**" in right panel
- Remove **iTunesHelper**
- Log off and back in (**MUST DO**)

and voilà !

Comment: I do not see iTunesHelper in my Login Items on mavericks

Comment: This didn't work for me in Mavericks

Comment: It is there in Yosemite, but need some time to see if disabling this really works

Comment: Works in macOS Sierra 10.12.3. And I didn't event needed to logoff/reboot. Just unpaired the headphones and paired them again. Never happened again.

Comment: I don't see iTunesHelper in Sierra 10.12.4 :(

Answer (score 5):

I just did this (Yes, I know this can be done in a single command, but it is clearer as two):

```
cd /Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/MacOS
sudo chmod 0 iTunes
```

And problem solved - no muss, no fuss (i.e., no prompts for "finding iTunes").

I'm guessing that this (just `chmod`ing the actual executable) is slightly sneakier than `chmod`ing the top level directory (`/Applications/iTunes.app`).  I'm guessing that that prevents it from thinking you've just moved it somewhere else.

Comment: Nice! In one line: `sudo chmod 0 /Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/MacOS/iTunes`

Comment: I still get "Operation not permitted" error on 10.13 even though I'm an admin.

Answer (score 5):

I am on a MacBook Air with Sierra, and all I had to do was:

1. Open iTunes
2. In iTunes Preferences choose the Devices tab.
3. On that tab check "Prevent iPods, iPhones, and iPads from syncing automatically"

That's it!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as the others no longer seem to work in High Sierra.

Comment: Agreed, this is the best solution!

Comment: This solution is not the best solution; because this doesn't stop a BT device from sending a media key system service that RCD intercepts, triggering the iTunes launch. This prevents _some_ things from triggering iTunes (e.g.: when plugging an iDevice…) but that's all it does.

Answer (score 4):

I'm on a MBP with osx 10.9.2. Disabling iTunes in "CD and DVD" preferences does not help. Just renaming iTunes to something else does not work.

The service "Remote Control Daemon", rdc, is responsible for delivering commands to (for example) iTunes. Use this script, [iTunesPatch](http://www.thebitguru.com/projects/iTunesPatch). This script modifies the actual binary for rdc to inhibit the command it sends to start iTunes, which means that all other functions of rdc still works as expected.

Answer (score 4):

I was also being driven mad with a new Plantronics Backbeat Pro headset, just a slight movement of the earpiece started iTunes.  I found I could disable the sensors on the headset.

Go to [plantronics.com/myheadset-updater](http://plantronics.com/myheadset-updater). You can download a program called MyHeadset Updater. It allows you to disable the sensors. You can also download the latest firmware.

Comment: new URL https://www.plantronics.com/au/en/support/downloads-apps/hub-desktop (or wherever you are) and go to Softphones and uncheck itunes. You need to plug your headphones in with the USB cable

Comment: so the uncheck itunes doesn't work (itunes was hiding in the background) so as the answer says, disable the sensors

Answer (score 4):

WORKING FIX; simplest and most effective solution (per mritunjai at https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2570254?start=75&tstart=0):

1. Open Terminal
2. Enter two separate commands:

   $ launchctl stop com.apple.rcd

   $ launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.rcd.plist

Comment: YES! This finally did the trick for me on Catalina 10.15.7

Comment: Note, I think you want `-w` to have to stay unloaded over restarts.

Comment: That said, this is no longer working for me on 10.15.7  with Sony WH-1000XM4. I can see that rcd is still unloaded, but Apple Music keeps opening up.

Comment: I tried this option on Catalina with Jabra Elite 75t headphones. Unfortunately, it means that none of the media keys on the touchbar work now, which I'm not willing to settle for. The fight continues...

Answer (score 2):

It is completely stupid and seemingly unrelated but it works:

In the CDs and DVDs preference pane disable iTunes to launch inserted for Audio CDs

your headset is an audio cd you know ;-)

Comment: Didn't work for me.

Comment: Make sure you restart the computer after doing this. It worked for me after a restart on a MacBook Pro (Mid 2012), El Capitan 10.11.4.

Comment: Very simple, very easy. Worked under Sierra. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Remove iTunes (you can reinstall later, but who would want to do that)

```
sudo rm -rf /Applications/iTunes
```

Create a "do nothing" application using Automator.  Just open Automator, create an empty application, and save it.

Connect your device.  You will be prompted to find iTunes.  Click <kbd>browse</kbd> and select your "do nothing" application.

Comment: Instead of removing iTunes a simple `sudo chmod 000 /Applications/iTunes.app` should be enough (and avoid the reinstall later on). To revert run `sudo chmod 755 /Applications/iTunes.app`

Comment: +1 for chmod. This worked for me on 10.9.5 using Beats Wireless.

Comment: LOL @"but who would want to do that"

Answer (score 2):

If you open Itunes and to the left of the play bar, select the regular speakers and not the headset. This stopped auto-start for me with up to date OS and Itunes (October 2017) and Plantronics Backbeat pro 2 headset.

Answer (score 1):

Update for Mojave: use [ToothFairy](https://itunes.apple.com/ie/app/toothfairy/id1191449274?mt=12) (note: not free but worth the money IMHO) to connect your bluetooth headphones and go to the Preferences > Advanced section. There you can add commands on connect and disconnect as described above by [mritun](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/145394/318135). See here (sorry for the bug with the font in Dark mode):

[image: ToothFairy Advanced Preferences]

This way you have the old behaviour back when you don't use your headphones.

I hope this helps other people!

Annard

Answer (score 1):

For MacBook Pro 16" and macOS 10.15.3 all solutions did not work. I did some research and found a way to disable Music. You won't be able to use it afterwards, so only do this if you do not need the Music app.

Since apple introduced some security mechanisms, some things have to be done in advance. At first you need to disable the System Integrity Protection.

> Boot in recovery mode (hold ⌘ + R until apple logo appears)
>
> Login with your user
>
> Open Terminal in Utilities Menu and enter
>
> `csrutil disable`
>
> reboot (normally)

Afterwards you have to mount your drive with write access because the apple applications are read only. This is non-permanent, after a reboot the changes are discarded.

> sudo mount -uw /

Now that the filesystem is writable, you can revoke all rights on Music to prevent it from being opened.

> sudo chmod 0 /System/Applications/Music.app/Contents/MacOS/Music

Now, connecting your bluetooth headset won't start the Music app.
But you have to turn System Integrity Protection on again:

> Boot in recovery mode
>
> Open Terminal in Utilities Menu and enter
>
> `csrutil enable`
>
> reboot (normally)

You can revert this change simply by giving the system the rights back to read, write, execute the Music App. Remember to turn off System Integrity Protection in advance and mount your drive writeable as stated above.

> sudo chmod 755 /System/Applications/Music.app/Contents/MacOS/Music

The Music App should be able to be used again.

Remeber to turn on System Integrity Protection again!

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, unloading the rcd launchd job is probably the best answer, see: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/273341/150839

However, I did not want to unload rcd completely, as I need it to control other applications such as QuickTime. I just wanted it to stop activating iTunes. So, I did an ugly hack:

1. Make a backup copy of /System/Library/CoreServices/rcd.app/Contents/MacOS/rcd
2. open /System/Library/CoreServices/rcd.app/Contents/MacOS/rcd in a hex editor such as Hex Fiend.
3. In ASCII mode, replace all instances of `iTunes` with `Finder`. (Finder was chosen primarily because it's the same number of characters as iTunes).
4. Now we have a fixed copy of the rcd binary, but we've broken its code signature! Because I keep Gatekeeper turned off anyway, I opted to remove the broken signature with https://www.insanelymac.com/forum/topic/293359-tool-to-remove-apple-code-signatures-from-binaries/ and leave the binary unsigned. You *may* be able to re-sign the binary with your own developer certificate instead; I did not attempt this as I don't actually have the developer tools installed.
5. Do a killall rcd so OS X reloads your new copy of the binary.

It should work now! Please note that I tested this procedure on Mac OS X 10.9.5 (Mavericks) which is very old as of this writing!

---

Update:

A few things I've discovered since writing this post:

1. Someone made a polished program that does the same thing as the above: https://thebitguru.com/projects/itunes-patch. You should use it instead of a hex editor... unless the situation below applies to you.
2. On the off chance you have removed iTunes from your machine completely (as I have), rcd is actually not what you need patch. The "Where Is iTunes" prompt isn't coming from rcd, but from `AVRCPAgent.app`, aka `/System/Library/CoreServices/AVRCPAgent.app/Contents/MacOS/AVRCPAgent /System/Library/CoreServices/AVRCPAgent.app/Contents/MacOS/`. The procedure I described above—replacing instances of "iTunes" with "Finder" in the Binary—does work, however.

If you happen to be on the final build of 10.9.5 (13F1911), here's a little shell script that will do everything for you. It won't work on other OS's because it's a binary patch (and it verifies the checksum before doing anything.)

https://gist.github.com/Wowfunhappy/8802a09c01f058b5fbd1945e7d6d7b1f

Comment: +1 for Mavericks (which I'm still using on one machine) but unfortunately this won't work on Catalina (10.15) since there are no occurences of "tell" in the binary. The Launch Daemon matches LaunchEvents matching against com.apple.rcdevent.matching and then starts up rcd when media buttons are pressed. A reference to this can be found in the method "setupEventHandling" with tools such as Ghidra.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issues with mine... but there is

1. [an app to route BT events to media keys](https://github.com/jguice/mac-bt-headset-fix)
2. an app to redirect media keys to specific apps: [Media Keys](http://www.gearmusicplayer.com/extras.html) by "Gear player" creator.

Answer (score -1):

Nothing worked for me, but I ripped the sensor out of my Bluedio T5S and now I don't have the issue any more. Actually made them a lot better as they would disconnect frequently just from moving around.

Answer (score -2):

so i was having this issue with my macbook where it was launching Itunes as soon as my headphone jack was plugged in.....i called Apple and they helped me disable it... here is how.

1. OPEN FINDER
2. GO TO APPLICATIONS
3. HIGHLIGHT ITUNES
4. RIGHT CLICK ITUNES AND CLICK "GET INFO"
5. UNLOCK SHARING PERMISSIONS BY CLICKING ON THE "LOCK ICON" BOTTOM RIGHT AND PUTTING IN YOUR LOG IN PASSWORD
6. WHERE IT SAYS "EVERYONE", SELECT THE DROP DOWN BOX AND SELECT "NO ACCESS"
7. LOCK THE "LOCK ICON"
8. RESTART (not necessary)AND PROBLEM SOLVED (FOR ME).

P.S. you will not be able to open itunes until you undo this process, hopes this help.

Answer (score -2):

Thank you this is the answer!  So easy!!!

Open iTunes
In iTunes Preferences choose the Devices tab.
On that tab check "Prevent iPods, iPhones, and iPads from syncing automatically"

Comment: This is just a "me too" of an earlier answer.