# Music app launches with bluetooth earbud connection in Catalina

Tags: macos, catalina, bluetooth, headphones, music.app

This has been [asked before](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/86315/prevent-itunes-from-opening-when-connecting-bluetooth-headset)  in the days of iTunes, but I'm still having trouble and the one Catalina-centric comment on that thread didn't work for me. I never want to use apple's music app, yet I manage to open on a daily basis by either connecting my bluetooth earbuds (Taotronics Liberty 79) or possibly by pressing the play/pause button on them. Sometimes it starts playing the few sad lonely songs I've purchased from apple. I want none of this and would uninstall Music.app if it were possible. Is there a way to prevent music from opening inadvertently like this? I've tried Music.app --> preference --> restrictions and checked all the boxes under "Disable:" (Music Profiles, Apple Music, iTunes Store, Shared Libraries).

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this web site](https://setapp.com/how-to/completely-uninstall-annoying-macos-apps) and scroll down to the 'Get rid of default mac apps' section and see if this works for you.