How do I stop Apple Music from launching, like when my headphones connect?
When my bluetooth headphones connect, Apple Music will often launch. What are some solutions?

Related https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/86315/prevent-itunes-from-opening-when-connecting-bluetooth-headset

Just for anyone reading, the reason this happens is because the headphones are sending play/pause commands and Apple Music is the default app to respond to that.

I found this solution to meet my needs. Got it setup in less than 2 minutes.
https://github.com/tombonez/noTunes?tab=readme-ov-file
I'm so thankful to have finally solved this problem that I happily donated using GitHub Support
